# Element binding not working in the ContextMenu of a ToggleButton in WPF

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, togglebutton

I have added a ContextMenu to a ToggleButton like this.

```
 <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButtonDateRange" Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="{icoMoon:IcoMoonFont}" FontSize="15" Template="{StaticResource DateRangeToggleButtonTemplate}">
                                        <ToggleButton.Style>
                                            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ChromelessButton}" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource DateRangeContextMenu}" />
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ToggleButton.Style>
                                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                            <behaviors:DropDownToggleButtonMenuBehavior/>
                                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    </ToggleButton>
```

The ContextMenu is defined like this:

```
                  <ContextMenu x:Key="DateRangeContextMenu" Style="{StaticResource DropdownCalendarContextMenuStyle}">
            <Grid Background="{StaticResource BrushBackgroundLight}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    Today Button
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="FromTab" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource TabControl}" Content="{Binding ElementName=FromCalendar, Path=SelectedDate}" GroupName="TabGroup" IsChecked="True" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{icoMoon:IcoMoon ArrowForward}" FontFamily="{icoMoon:IcoMoonFont}" 
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" 
                                               Foreground="{StaticResource DarkSlateGrayBackgroundColor}"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="ToTab" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TabControl}" Content="{Binding ElementName=ToCalendar, Path=SelectedDate}" GroupName="TabGroup" />
                </Grid>

                <Border Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=FromTab, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <controls:CalendarAutoDefocus x:Name="FromCalendar" Background="{StaticResource BrushContentWhite}" BorderThickness="0" 
                                                                      SelectedDate="{Binding SearchStartDate}" DisplayDateEnd="{Binding ElementName=ToCalendar, Path=SelectedDate}" DisplayDate="{Binding CalendarStartDisplayDate}"
                                                                      SingleClickDefocus="False"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ToTab, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <controls:CalendarAutoDefocus x:Name="ToCalendar" Background="{StaticResource BrushContentWhite}" BorderThickness="0"
                                                                      SelectedDate="{Binding SearchEndDate}" DisplayDateStart="{Binding ElementName=FromCalendar, Path=SelectedDate}" DisplayDate="{Binding CalendarEndDisplayDate}"
                                                                      SingleClickDefocus="False"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ContextMenu>
```

Problem:

RadioButtons FromTab and ToTab are not binding to elements FromCalender and ToCalender.

How can we fix the element binding issue?

Please help!

Thanks,
Sath

Comment: The property SelectedDate is a boolean object which you are binding to the radiobutton?

Comment: Hi Aakansksha! SelectedDate is a date property and Radio button has been retemplated to show the SelectedDate value. Thanks. :)

Comment: Your FromCalender element has SelectedDate property?